# What is the Document Etag and where I find it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, online

I'm working with documents in SharePoint Online and I'm not understanding what is the Etag and how I can find it or retrieve.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

eTag in SharePointing world is vast topics, to make it sort :

In SharePoint the ETag is part of the file properties which are stored together with the file in the content database.

More understanding on eTag :

https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/improving-performance-of-sharepoint-sites/part-13-etag-header/

How to see or retrieve the eTag from SharePoint online?

The "**fileID**" property of a document is nothing but eTag property. We can see this thru document URL... and in programmatic way or MS Flow or Nintex workflow or PowerShell coding we can retrieve the eTag value.

**Please see the below MS Flow example :**

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Usage-of-the-ETag/td-p/77679

https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/docx/viewer/teams/https:~2F~2F.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2F~2FDocuments~2F~2F.docx?threadId=19:@thread.skype&baseUrl=https:~2F~2F.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2F&**fileId=285CAB80-E9E9-441E-822C-3A486EDFA7F4**&ctx=files&viewerAction=view

In the above example the bold fileId is eTag

**Updated(added code sample screenshot):**

I have just tried using PowerShell to retrieve the document eTag Property - its like below:

[image: Getting eTag Property from a document using PowerShell]